# Jackson: Ignore Json configuration value

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following json file:

```
{
  "segments": {        
            "externalId": 123, 
            "name": "Tomas Zulberti", 
            "shouldInform": true, 
            "id": 4
   }
}
```

But the java model is as follows:

```
public class Segment {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private boolean shouldInform;

    // getter and setters here...
}
```

When Jackson is parsing it raises an exception becuase there is no getter or setter for the field "externalId". It there a decorator that can be used to ignore a json field?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties`; if it's just one value you want to skip, something like:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"externalId"})
```

or to ignore anything that can't be used:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
```

There are other ways to do it too, for rest check out [FasterXML Jackson wiki](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToIgnoreUnknown).

Comment: The linked FasterXML Jackson wiki does no longer exist.

Answer (score 2):

Also we can use mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.**FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES**);
instead @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)

but for particular property we can use

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"externalId"})
public class Segment {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private boolean shouldInform;

    // getter and setters here...
}
```