# Ignore specific field on serialization with Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm using the Jackson library.

I want to ignore a specific field when serializing/deserializing, so for example:

```
public static class Foo {
    public String foo = "a";
    public String bar = "b";

    @JsonIgnore
    public String foobar = "c";
}
```

Should give me:

```
{
foo: "a",
bar: "b",
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
{
foo: "a",
bar: "b",
foobar: "c"
}
```

I'm serializing the object with this code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String out = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Foo());
```

The real type of the field on my class is an instance of the Log4J Logger class. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Ok, so for some reason I missed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168095/jackson-ignore-json-configuration-value).

The following code works as expected:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"foobar"})
public static class Foo {
    public String foo = "a";
    public String bar = "b";

    public String foobar = "c";
}

//Test code
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.foobar = "foobar";
foo.foo = "Foo";
String out = mapper.writeValueAsString(foo);
Foo f = mapper.readValue(out, Foo.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting is this solution using DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18850479/1256179

Answer (score 0):

Reference from [How can I tell jackson to ignore a property for which I don't have control over the source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421474/how-can-i-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-property-for-which-i-dont-have-control-over)

You can use Jackson Mixins. For example:

```
class YourClass {
  public int ignoreThis() { return 0; }    
}
```

With this Mixin

```
abstract class MixIn {
  @JsonIgnore abstract int ignoreThis(); // we don't need it!  
}
```

With this:

```
objectMapper.addMixIn(YourClass.class, MixIn.class);
```