# How to serialize automatically all Annotated fields in JsonSerializer class

Tags: java, jackson

I've written my CustomJsonSerializer and I would like it to automatically serialize all fields that are annotated using @JsonProperty so I would only left serializing the ones which are not annotated and need "special care".

For example: I have the Pojo

class Player {

```
@JsonProperty(user_id)
private long userId;

private byte[] history;
}
```

My custom Serializer:

```
public class JsonPlayerSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Player> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Player player, JsonGenerator gen,    
         SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

          // I would like to add some code here that automatically would add all annotated fields.

          gen.writeObjectField("history_moves", new JsonObject().put("$binary", myMoves));
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168095/jackson-ignore-json-configuration-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   class Player {

     @JsonProperty(user_id)
     private long userId;

     @JsonIgnore
     private byte[] history;
    }
```

In your custom serializer call the parent serializer method  so it would continue serialization.

```
public class JsonPlayerSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Player> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Player player, JsonGenerator gen,    
         SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {


          super.serialize(player,gen,provider);   
          gen.writeObjectField("history_moves", new JsonObject().put("$binary", myMoves));
    }
}
```

**Or**
As mentioned here
[Jackson JSON custom serialization for certain fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046786/jackson-json-custom-serialization-for-certain-fields)

```
 class Player {

         @JsonProperty(user_id)
         private long userId;

         @JsonSerialize(using = JsonPlayerSerializer .class)
         private byte[] history;
        }
```

Use the the serializer only for the history field

```
public class JsonPlayerSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Player> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Player player, JsonGenerator gen,    
         SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

          gen.writeObjectField("history_moves", new JsonObject().put("$binary", myMoves));
    }
}
```